# Why does the header set X-Robots-Tag apply to all pages?

Tags: htaccess, headers, noindex, nofollow

The directives below are intended to apply the header `X-Robots-Tag` `noindex` and `nofollow` to a single page.

The directives below are applied before the WordPress code block however it appears to result in all pages being set with `noindex` and `nofollow`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?faq?(/)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^faq - [E=NOINDEXNOFOLLOW]
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" E=NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
```

The `E` flag is being used for LiteSpeed as opposed to `ENV` for Apache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The `E` flag is being used for LiteSpeed as opposed to `ENV` for Apache.

Where did you get this from? The [LiteSpeed docs](https://www.litespeedtech.com/docs/webserver/config/context/static#extraHeaders) appear to show that LiteSpeed is the same as Apache in this respect and require `env=`, not `E=`, on the `Header` directive in order to conditionally set the HTTP response header based on the presence of an environment variable.

Having tested this myself on a LiteSpeed server I can confirm that this does appear to be the case. And this would seem to be the problem with your directive above. Using `E=` would seem to result in the header being set *unconditionally*, which appears to be what you are seeing. (How LiteSpeed actually interprets `E=<var>` is unclear - it may just "ignore" it!? In my experience, LiteSpeed seems to just "ignore" directives/syntax that it does not understand - no error is generated, which makes debugging troublesome!)

*Aside:* On Apache you would also have issues with how environment variables are renamed when the rewriting process starts over - after WordPress rewrites the request to `index.php`. For example, on Apache you would need to test for `REDIRECT_NOINDEXNOFOLLOW`, as opposed to `NOINDEXNOFOLLOW`. However, this does not seem to be the case with LiteSpeed.

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)?faq?(/)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^faq - [E=NOINDEXNOFOLLOW]
> ```

*Aside:* Your `RewriteCond` would seem to be unnecessary (and overly complex). And the `RewriteCond` (*condition*) and `RewriteRule` directives *conflict* to some extent... You have made the `RewriteCond` case-insensitive, however, the `RewriteRule` is not, so whilst the *condition* would match `FaQ`, the `RewriteRule` only matches `faq` (all lowercase). The `RewriteCond` matches `fa` (since the trailing `q` is optional), however, the `RewriteRule` matches only `faq` (since the trailing `q` is not optional here).

So, the above could be written as a single directive:

```
RewriteRule ^faq/$ - [E=NOINDEXNOFOLLOW]
```

NB: Note that when setting an environment variable with mod_rewrite, without a stated value, it is set to an *empty* string. (This is different to mod_env and mod_setenvif that would set the variable to `1`.) As it happens, this does not cause a problem with the `Header` directive.

However, if you are simply setting an env var based on the requested URL then I would use `SetEnvIf` (mod_setenvif) instead of mod_rewrite. For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/faq/$ NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
```

Note that this sets the variable to `1`, instead of an empty string.

### Summary

You should use the following on LiteSpeed instead:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/faq/$ NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
```

On Apache, you would need to modify the `Header` directive to test the `REDIRECT_NOINDEXNOFOLLOW` instead (as mentioned above). For example:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/faq/$ NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow" env=REDIRECT_NOINDEXNOFOLLOW
```